# How to run code when the user unlocks the screen using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is is possible to run code once the user unlocks the screen for both devices IOS and Android and the app is terminated?.

I tried to use this package [screen_state](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_state) and its not working when the app is terminated.